# Cant install python3-pyqt5 on ubuntu 17

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I`m trying to install python3-pyqt5, but still getting the same error. I tried reinstalling ubuntu, updating and upgrading my apt-get and still no clue whats wrong.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: Please post your answer as solution instead of Editing the question and adding the solution. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that I just needed to type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After doing some reading, I was able to install pyqt5 using this workaround:

1. Install python3-setuptools:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
   ```
2. Install pip:

   ```
   $ sudo easy_install3 pip
   ```
3. Finally, install pyqt5 using pip:

   ```
   $ pip3 install --user pyqt5
   ```